# How to store last value of parameter in parameterized job as a default value for next build in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have been using Jenkins for a few weeks and I have one small problem. I can't find any plugin or solution for storing the last value of a parameter in a parametrized job as a default value for the next build.

For example:
My parameter takes build version (1.0.0.01) in the first build. In the next build it will be changed to 1.0.0.02, but I want to have a 1.0.0.01 in the default value field as a hint.
Does anybody have a solution or advice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a System groovy build step to your job (or maybe a post build Groovy step) using the Jenkins API to directly modify the project setting the default parameter value.

Here is some code that may be useful to get you started:

```
import hudson.model.*

paramsDef = build.getParent().getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class)
if (paramsDef) {
  paramsDef.parameterDefinitions.each{ param ->
    if (param.name == 'FOO') {
      println("Changing parameter ${param.name} default value was '${param.defaultValue}' to '${param.defaultValue} BAR'")
      param.defaultValue = "${param.defaultValue} BAR"
    }
  }
}
```

Have a look at the class [ParameterDefinition](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/ParameterDefinition.html) in the Jenkins model.

You probably need to modify the default param value based on the current build executing. Some code to get that would look like this:

```
def thisBuildParamValue = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve('FOO')
```

Comment: Thanks for that code sample. The problem is that new value isn't stored between restarts of jenkins. As long as the jenkins isn't restarted the default value will be changed and new one used in next build. But if jenkins is restarted default value will fall back to the last manually added value. Is it possible to make this new value "hard stored"?

Comment: @macg33zr do u know it it's possible to utilize your proposal in jenkins declarative pipeline somehow ?

Answer (score 13):

The [Persistent Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Persistent+Parameter+Plugin) is exactly what you are looking for!

You just need to download it from the official Jenkins repository and install it, no need for any additional setup.

Then on your job, you just need to add a "Persistent Parameter" in order to have default values used and saved between builds.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13216452)

Comment: This comment and the minus vote doesn't make sense at all because the solution is a downloadable Jenkins plugin, there is no way to "include the essential parts of the answer" here...

Comment: It does make sense because you can write more information about this plugin: how to use it, some examples, etc. For example, I have no idea what's that and this link wouldn't help much if I can set up properly. :)

Comment: what does the Successful Only checkbox mean?

Comment: It will only persist the value if the build was successful.

Answer (score 1):

The [Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) plugin provides this capability by using default parameter values from a properties file. A default parameter can be selected from a specified property key and this key can be programmatically modified in your current build. I would then use a groovy script in the current build to set the value of the default property key for the next build.

As an example you would have an Extended Choice Parameter whose default value is defined by a properties file **version.properties** with keys as follows:

```
versions=1.0.0.02, 1.0.0.01, 1.0.0.00
default.version=1.0.0.02
```

The parameter definition would include:

```
Property File=version.properties    
Property Key=versions
Default Property File=version.properties
Default Property Key=default.versions
```

The GUI for your parameter in the next build would show a selection list with 1.0.0.02 selected by default. This feature is also very useful for pipeline builds where you would want the parameters of a downstream build stage to be set by an earlier build.

The only drawback to this approach might be that the parameter UI will be a drop-down selection. You may opt to have a single value in the versions property key so not to confuse your users.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to thiagolr's answer, but for those of you using pipelines! It appears the persistent-parameter-plugin doesn't work for those using pipeline 2.0. But there is a patched version at https://github.com/ashu16815/persistent-parameter-plugin which seems to work for me.

Clone it locally:
git clone https://github.com/ashu16815/persistent-parameter-plugin.git

Build it:
mvn clean install

Install it in Jenkins:
1) Navigate to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins
2) Click Advanced tab
3) Scroll down to Upload Plugin
4) Click Choose file and select the persistent-parameter.hpi in the target directory of the maven build above

Now it should persist.

Comment: How do you set the persistent parameters from the pipeline?

Comment: Did you find a solution @jjcf89?

Comment: No. We wanted a way to set a default in the pipeline script but override it per job. But the pipeline script always overrides whats set in the job config. The best way we've found is to not put the parameter in the Jenkins script and set it in the jenkins job config only...

Answer (score 0):

The requested behaviour can be easily accomplished this Jenkins pipelines and without any plugin. E.g.:

```js
pipeline {
    agent { label any }

    parameters {
        string(name: 'BUILD_VER',
              defaultValue: params.BUILD_VER ? params.BUILD_VER : '1.0.0.00',
              description: 'Build version')
    }
...
}
```

In Jenkins pipelines `params` contains the job/build parameter values for *current* build. That HashMap is initialized *before* the `parameters` *definition block* is evaluated. That re-evaluation happens on *each build*. So:

1. On 1st build, `params` will be empty as `parameters` has not been evaluated yet, so `params.BUILD_VER` does not exist, and '1.0.0.00' is used to initialize `defaultValue` for the *next* build.
2. On 2nd build, the parameter will be offered/shown with default value '1.0.0.00'. Changing the value to e.g. '1.0.0.05' and running the build with that parameter value will save '1.0.0.05' as `defaultValue` for the *next* build.
3. Beginning with 3rd build, the default value will be the one from the previous build.